# Writing to file random loss and gain of 0s

Tags: python, file, csv, random

I am writing a python script to convert old DayLite contacts into CSV format to be imported into Outlook. I have a script that functions completely almost perfectly except for one small issue but due to being mass data fixing it in the file will take way to long.

The list of contacts is very long 1,100+ rows in the spreadsheet. When the text gets written into the CSV file everything is good except certain/random phone numbers lose their leading 0 and gain a '.0' at the end. However the majority of the phone numbers are left in the exact format.

This is my script code:

```
import xlrd
import xlwt
import csv
import numpy

##########################
# Getting XLS Data sheet #
##########################

oldFormatContacts = xlrd.open_workbook('DayliteContacts_Oct16.xls')
ofSheet = oldFormatContacts.sheet_by_index(0)

##################################
# Storing values in array medium #
##################################

rowVal = [''] * ofSheet.nrows

x = 1

for x in range(ofSheet.nrows):
    rowVal[x] = (ofSheet.row_values(x))

######################
# Getting CVS titles #
######################

csvTemp = xlrd.open_workbook('Outlook.xls')
csvSheet = csvTemp.sheet_by_index(0)
csv_title = csvSheet.row_values(0)

rowVal[0] = csv_title

##############################################################
# Append and padding data to contain commas for empty fields #
##############################################################

x = 0
q = '"'

for x in range(ofSheet.nrows):
    temporaryRow = rowVal[x]
    temporaryRow = str(temporaryRow).strip('[]')
    if x > 0:
        rowVal[x] = (','+str(q+temporaryRow.split(',')[0]+q)+',,'+str(q+temporaryRow.split(',')[1]+q)+',,'+str(q+temporaryRow.split(',')[2]+q)+',,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,'+str(q+temporaryRow.split(',')[4]+q)+','+str(q+temporaryRow.split(',')[6]+q)+',,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,'+str(q+temporaryRow.split(',')[8])+q)

    j = 0
    for j in range(0,21):
        rowVal[x] += ','
    tempString = str(rowVal[x])
    tempString = tempString.replace("'","")
    #tempString = tempString.replace('"', '')
    #tempString = tempString.replace(" ", "")
    rowVal[x] = tempString

######################################
# Open and write values too new file #
######################################

csv_file = open('csvTestFile.csv', 'w')

rownum = 0

for rownum in range(ofSheet.nrows):
    csv_file.write(rowVal[rownum])
    csv_file.write("\n")

csv_file.close()
```

Sorry if my coding is incoherent I am a beginner to python scripts.

Unfortunately I cannot show or provide the contact details due to privacy reasons however I will give some examples in the exact format that it occurs.

So in the DayLite document a contact would be saved as "First name, Second name, Company, phone number 1, phone number 2, email" for example: 
"Joe, Black, Stack Overflow, 07472329584," 
but when written into the CSV file it will be 
"Joe","Black","Stack Overflow","7472329584.0".

This is odd because for each occurrence of that problem there will be 10 or so fine numbers that get saved exactly the same e.g. In DayLite: "+446738193583" when written in CSV: "+446738193583".

I forgot to mention (this is an edit) that many phone numbers KEEP their leading 0 and do not gain a trailing 0. It's probably 1/20 phone numbers that gets messed up.

It seems to me to be a very weird error and this is why I have come here for help! If anyone has any ideas I'd be more than happy to hear them. Cheers guys.

Comment: Obviously, the problem is that fields consisting entirely of digits are being treated as a number, rather than a string.  The CSV module you're using may have some way of specifying the format for each field; if not, it's probably not the right tool for this job.

Comment: @jasonharper but I pass in the numbers as a string when placing the quotations around the number. Which CSV module? Are you talking about xlrd? I used to use the CSV import but it wasn't functioning correctly in my script.

Comment: @jasonharper so I took the numbers and forced them into a string and used that instead, this did not work so I don't think you're correct, unless I'm missing something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue lied within the Excel document but I assumed it lied within my script. I placed an ' before each number that was causing a format error. This meant when read from the sheet there was no issues with format and it wrote it back to the file successfully.